# How can I scrape this page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a page, but I'm getting errors trying to scrape `WANTED-DATA`

```
<td class="class-1" data-reactid="41"><a class="class-2" data-reactid="42" data-symbol="MORE-DATA" href="/quote/HKxlkPH4-x" title="WANTED-DATA">text</a></td>
```

The closer thing I can extract is `text` by doing:

```
getText.find('a', attrs={'class':'class-2'}).text
# output: 'text'
```

How can I scrape `'WANTED-DATA'`?

Comment: Hello, try something like this:

`links = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'class-2'}).text
for link in links:
    title = link.get('title')`

Comment: @grumpyp it worked, thank you! Write it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: nice to hear, I´ve added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
links = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'class-2'}).text 
for link in links:     
    title = link.get('title')
```

Answer (score 1):

from the [`docs`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes). You can write `tag[attr_name]` to get single attribute and `tag.attrs` lo get a dictionary of all attributes with values.

```
soup.find('a', attrs={'class':'class-2'})['title']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it also like this:

```
html = """<td class="class-1" data-reactid="41"><a class="class-2" data-reactid="42" data-symbol="MORE-DATA" href="/quote/HKxlkPH4-x" title="WANTED-DATA">text</a></td>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
## adding title=True below prevent any error in case you have links without the 'title attribute'
titles = [x.get('title') for x in soup.find_all('a',title=True)]
print(titles)
```

Output:

```
['WANTED-DATA']
```